# Difference between @(posedge Clk); a<= 1'b1; and @(posedge Clk) a<= 1'b1;

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is there any difference between

```
@(posedge Clk);
   a<= 1'b1;
```

and

```
@(posedge Clk)
   a<= 1'b1;
```

Note the semicolon after Clk. I came across similar lines of code when I was browsing through a testbench. I did some simple experiments and I could not find any differences during simulation. Will the sequence of execution for the code following these lines change in any way due to the presence/absence of the semicolon?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're correct -there's no behavioural difference.

The semicolon version is: Wait. Do this.
The non-semicolon version is: Wait then do this. You'll sometimes see this form used in one-liners:

```
@(posedge Clk) a<= 1'b1;
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. There are difference depending on the context.

Answer (score 21):

The BNF syntax for any procedural statement is essentially

```
statement_item := 
        {procedural_timing_control} statement;
```

This means you can have 0 or more timing controls in front of any statement. In your example `@(posedge Clk)` is a timing control and `a<= 1'b1;` is the statement.

If your example were inside a fork/join, there would be a behavioral difference because the former is two statements; the later is one statement.

```
fork
  @(posedge Clk); a<=1'b1;
join
```

In this case, the 2 statements are started in parallel - `a` would not wait for the posedge to be assigned.